# How do I locate the line causing the error in a SparkR script?

Tags: r, sparkr

I can't debug my program because I don't know what line the error occurred on (it's not part of the R error message). Usually I put `print` statements into my code so when it executes I know how far it's gotten, but R seems to throw away all the `print()` output when an error occurs at run-time.

This simple script demonstrates the problem:

```
%r
print(1)
print(no_such_variable)
print(2)
```

When executed, this script will cause an error because `no_such_variable` is not defined. But in Spark Databricks, the displayed result is:

```
Error in print(no_such_variable) : object 'no_such_variable' not found Error in print(no_such_variable) : object 'no_such_variable' not found
Error in print(no_such_variable) : object 'no_such_variable' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) :
```

There's no line number associated with the error, and no output from my `print` statements. Obviously I could send the print output to a file (and presumably flush it after each statement), but this seems a long way to go for something I've been doing since I started writing Basic code in 1975.

How are people programming complex R code in Spark without being able to see what's going on in their code? I really hope I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 0):

`message` prints text represented as conditions. In Databricks, it will get printed even if there is another condition (like an error).

```
message("Print1")
message(no_such_variable)
message("Print2")
#> Print1
#> Error in message(no_such_variable) : object 'no_such_variable' not found
```

Comment: Requiring developers in 2023 to annotate every line with print statements to isolate where errors happen seems like a major step backwards.